# R code shows error: undefined columns selected on one computer, but not on the other

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm working on an R project for a client and I wrote one function that works on my machine but not on his. He sent me a screenshot with an error he gets. I can't post the actual code because it shows no errors on my computer so I'm posting a screenshot I got from him :
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJjrS.png). 
The function is called "evaluation_loop(npl_order)" npl_order is an integer parameter. The function returns a dataframe. and  among other thing in the function, I'm subsetting 
local dataframes df_deps_t1 and df_deps_t2 (which contain 4 columns and 199 rows) like this:

df_deps_t1[, npl_order]

df_deps_t2[, npl_order]

On my computer everything is fine, but on his error shows up saying: Undefined columns selected. You can see the function call in the R console  on the screenshot.
Any ideas why this is happening? 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you have a 'empty' environment when running the code on your machine? Try to run the code on a new R session (**without** loading any .RData etc) and see if you still don't get an error.

Comment: Very broad question, lacking a bit of information. He uses the same function, but is he using the same data as input? What is the value of `npl_order`with your client? etc.

Comment: Without a reproducible example there is no definite diagnosis possible. One possibility would be this: `npl_order <- NA; iris[, npl_order]`

Comment: @dario I created a new project, put all scripts and data in the project directory, open up RStudio from there with the empty environment, and I still didn't get an error.

Comment: Hm, is the other person using the same data? And if yes: Reading it from a file (some R functions use locale settings for deliminator and decimal separator which could lead to such inconsistent "magic" behaviour...
Without additional information it's going to be very difficult to tell though...

Comment: SOLVED: I instructed him to do the same: creating new project to make sure that the environment is empty and it worked. I really hate R, it's like it gets "drunk" sometimes. I frequently get similar inconsistencies.  Thanks everyone.